# nested loop will not iterate in random password generator

Tags: python

I have having trouble with my num_char output in my random password generator. I am getting the number of passwords but not the length on each password. Can you solve this?

```
from random import choice
import string

def create_password():

    num_passwords = int(input('How many passwords would you like?  '))
    num_char = int(input('How long would you like your password to be?  '))
    
    for j in range(num_passwords):
        for k in range(num_char):
            password = ''.join([choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)])
            num_passwords -=1
        print(password)

create_password()
```

output:

```
y
t
K
S
7
```

Comment: Did you even try to use a debugger on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `list comprehension`

Also, you don't need `num_passwords -=1`

And this

```
password = ''.join([choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)])
```

Will give you something like `a` per password

```
from random import choice
import string

def create_password():

    num_passwords = int(input('How many passwords would you like?  '))
    num_char = int(input('How long would you like your password to be?  '))
    
    for j in range(num_passwords):
        pwd = [choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for k in range(num_char)]
        print(''.join(pwd))
create_password()
```

output **(num_pwd = 5, num_char = 5)**

```
VY1bi
jAvLG
zUxlo
jMBZD
VQHV6
```

Answer (score 1):

this maybe easier to understand for beginer.
but list comprehension is better solution

```py
from random import choice
import string

def create_password():

    num_passwords = int(input('How many passwords would you like?  '))
    num_char = int(input('How long would you like your password to be?  '))
    
    for j in range(num_passwords):
        password = ''
        for k in range(num_char):
            #in your code.you just replace password to last one every time
            password += ''.join([choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)])
            # num_passwords -=1 #no need for this
        print(password)

create_password()
```